# Jquery Accordion background color

Tags: jquery, css

Hello guys I started Jquery and I wanted to use accordion to some forms I have. I did the h3,div,form and in script.js I used

```
$(".ui-accordion-content").css("background-color", "#CACACA"); //Doesn't make metal grey all arcodion
$("form").css("background-color", "#CACACA"); //It does the form metal grey but I still have some white space openings and I don't know why.
```

Comment: By the way when I use accordion I use this parameters $(".leftsidebar").accordion({collapsible: true, active: false,heightStyle: "content"});

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is not clear but I think this could help:

```
$(".ui-accordion-content").css("background-color", "#CACACA");.
$(".ui-accordion-content *").css("background-color", "#CACACA");
```

In Firefox right click on white piece to see element and it's styles.

Comment: Thanks for response, I tried this and unfortunately the same rectangular
white spaces are still there, the only thing it changed was the input inside the form which turns into metal grey from the white they were.

Comment: So there probable you have an element upon the accordion. Because with the code all children elements of accordion will be gray. I think the white piece is not children of accordion. For test you can use this one: `$(".ui-accordion-content *").css("background-color", "#CACACA!important");`

Answer (score 0):

Right click on those white spaces and inspect their element. They possibly are just default margin and padding styles. Do you use reset.css?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, accordion in order to put the forms in the middle it was using in ui-accordiont-content padding: 1em 2.2em. The only thing I did was to add this in the script.

```
$(".ui-accordion-content").css("padding","0em");
```

Another way is if you still want your forms in the accordion's default position but you have bugs with the bg colors you just type

```
$(".ui-accordion-content").css("background-color", "color you want");
$(".ui-widget-content").css("background", "color you want");
```